# Is it possible to enter the Schengen area as a tourist while a German work visa request is in process?

Tags: schengen, germany, schengen-visas, tourist-visas, venezuelan-citizens

My girlfriend is from Venezuela and she is in the process of requesting a work visa for Germany at the German embassy in Santiago de Chile (as she will obtain her Chilean residency soon).

While the visa request is in process (ie: after the interview at the German embassy), **is she allowed to travel as a tourist in the Schengen area**?

*Additional information*

I do not know if it is relevant but during this tourist trip, she would enter Schengen through Italy or Spain and spend most of the time in Switzerland.

My understanding is that as she is from Venezuela, she does not need a Schengen visa and she should therefore be allowed to enter as a tourist.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the reference to 2021?

Comment: @Traveller: I was referring to the ETIAS (https://www.etiasvisa.com/es/requisitos-etias/venezuela). I will remove it, it's actually not relevant for the question.

Comment: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11503/2212 covers a different but similar scenario where they needed a tourist visa and it says "I was told at the South African German Consulate that I am not allowed to apply for a tourist visa after handing in my application for a long-term visa." this does not bode well for your case but at the same it's possible it's a quirk of the visa processing system and not the actual admissions. So I do not know what happens in a visa free situation but I thought this is relevant.

Comment: @chx thanks for sharing this thread! It seems that as he had to apply for two visas, the situation is a bit different. From the question, it seems it is possible to at least enter Schengen, go back to the original country and apply, and go back while waiting. I hope we don't have to first enter Schengen though, that would be very expensive and would delay everything :/

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question. There was no problem at all to enter Schengen as a tourist while the visa was being processed at the German embassy in Santiago. This was confirmed at the embassy. She just had to come back to Chile to pick-up the visa.

Comment: We love users like you who come back and update the community on their experience. Thanks a lot!